# disable react css transition group on certain events

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I currently have a dashboard type app that pulls messages out of multiple slack channels and displays the ones without any replies or emojis. You can change which channel you want to view.

Currently, the parent state looks something like this:

```
state = {
        selected_channel: window.localStorage.getItem( 'last-slack-ch' ) || 'ABC123'
        selected_date: new Date(),
        channels: {},
        items: [],
        slack_users: {},
        settings: {
            seconds_per_slack_messages_pull: 1
        },
        atBottom: false
    }
```

After pulling in the messages... or `items`, I pass that array into a component `ItemsContainer`.

This is the render method in `ItemsContainer`

```
render() { 

        return (
            <div className="items-container">
                {
                    this.props.items.length > 0 ?
                        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                            transitionName='item'
                            transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                            transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                        {
                            this.props.items.map( t => { 
                                return (
                                    <Item 
                                        key={ t.usr + '_' + t.ts } 
                                        task={ t } 
                                        user={ this.props.slack_users[ t.usr ] } 
                                        settings={ this.props.settings } 
                                    /> 
                                )
                            } )
                        }
                        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                    :
                        <p className='nothing-found'>No items were found in channel: { this.props.selected_channel }</p>
                }

            </div>
        );
    }
```

**The issue I am currently facing** is that there are certain events that I don't want to have a transition. Stuff like: Initial page load and switching channels.

I tried passing in some props to `ItemsContainer` which will determine what transitionName to the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`... but things didnt really work too well.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Have you tried `transitionEnter={false}` or `transitionLeave={false}` to disable animation? https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html#disabling-animations

Comment: wouldnt that disable the transition entirely though. I still need the transitions when new messages come in. @chin8628

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your code exactly how you would implement it, but you could add a `key` property to the top-level `div` in your `ItemsContainer` component. The `key` property is usually used to identify children in collections but can be used outside of those cases. When a key changes, React creates a new component instance rather than re-render the existing (https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key).

So try re-writing `ItemsContainer` as:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div className="items-container" key={this.props.selected_channel}>
      // Transition code that will only apply within the selected channel.
    </div>
  );
}
```

This should solve the switching-channel problem. So when `ItemsContainer` receives a new `props.selected_channel` value you should avoid the transition animations.